# how to parse html table with php

Tags: php

I would really appreciate if somebody could give me a hint on how to parse this kind of tables and show results in a specific order.

So the piece of html I have is

```
<table name="maintable" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="3" border="0" id="grid_block" width="100%" class="csm">
<tr class="shade" style="font-weight: bold">
    <td width="30%">Name</td>
    <td width="70%">NameOne</td>
</tr>
<tr class="shade" style="font-weight: bold">
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>2012-09-30</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<table name="maintable" cellspacing=2 cellpadding=3 border=0 id="grid_block" width="100%" class="csm">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="12" align="center" bgcolor="#90ee90"><b>In Stock</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr onmouseover="this.className = 'rowselected';" onmouseout="this.className = 'shade';">
            <td class="greenshade"><b>Color/Size</b></td>
            <td align="center" class="greenshade"><b>OO</b></td>
            <td align="center" class="greenshade"><b>0</b></td>
            <td align="center" class="greenshade"><b>2</b></td>
            <td align="center" class="greenshade"><b>4</b></td>
            <td align="center" class="greenshade"><b>6</b></td>
            <td align="center" class="greenshade"><b>8</b></td>
            <td align="center" class="greenshade"><b>10</b></td>
            <td align="center" class="greenshade"><b>12</b></td>
            <td align="center" class="greenshade"><b>14</b></td>
            <td align="center" class="greenshade"><b>16</b></td>
            <td align="center" class="greenshade"><b>18</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr onmouseover="this.className = 'rowselected';" onmouseout="this.className = 'shade';">
                <td width='30%' ><b>black</b></td>
                <td align="Center">-</td>
                <td align="Center">-</td>
                <td align="Center">-</td>
                <td align="Center">-</td>
                <td align="Center">-</td>
                <td align="Center">-</td>
                <td align="Center">-</td>
                <td align="Center">-</td>
                <td align="Center">-</td>
                <td align="Center">-</td>
                <td align="Center">-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr onmouseover="this.className = 'rowselected';" onmouseout="this.className = 'shade';">
                <td width='30%' ><b>nude</b></td>
                <td align="Center">-</td>
                <td align="Center">-</td>
                <td align="Center">-</td>
                <td align="Center">-</td>
                <td align="Center">-</td>
                <td align="Center">-</td>
                <td align="Center">-</td>
                <td align="Center">-</td>
                <td align="Center">-</td>
                <td align="Center">-</td>
                <td align="Center">-</td>
        </tr>
```

and the problem is that I need to parse this table and output it in this form:

;nameOne;black;OO;-;

;nameOne;black;0;-;

;nameOne;black;2;-;

etc.

so basically - name(from the first table), color, size, quantity; for every color and size.

I have been trying to accomplish this for the last two days and no luck so far, so I would appreciate any help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this library https://github.com/olamedia/nokogiri for parsing html data.
Say you want convert this stuff to array, here how you can do this:

```
$saw = new nokogiri($big_html_string);
$my_table = $saw->get('table')->toArray();
```

And after that you have array with all attributes and nodes, see `print_r($my_table)`
Notice that $big_html_string should be the whole html with `<html>, <body>` tags!